# Library for converting PDF/DOC(X)/XLS to EPUB in Android

Tags: android, library, java, document-converter, epub

I am designing a new app which is used to convert PDF, DOC, DOCX and XLS format into the EPUB format.

Is there any library I could use for this?

Answer (score 0):

You can check out the [LEADTOOLS Documents Converter SDK](https://www.leadtools.com/sdk/document/document-converter) which has support for converting to and from the following Document Formats:

- Adobe Acrobat **PDF** and **PDF/A**
- Microsoft Office **DOC/DOCX, XLS/XLSX**, PPT/PPTX, PST, EML, MSG, and XPS formats
- CAD formats such as DXF, DWG, and DWF
- TIFF, JPEG, PNG, EXIF, BMP, and hundreds more raster image formats using OCR
- Plain Text, RTF, HTML, MOBI, **ePUB**

Disclaimer: I am an employee of this library

Answer (score 0):

While I can't vouch for it meeting all of your needs, Google Drive/Apps has recently added support for epub files.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if calibre has a library underneath, but it might be a good start as it is opensource and already allows to convert many formats to epub.

Link: [Calibre](https://calibre-ebook.com/) / [Github project](https://github.com/kovidgoyal/calibre)